# Either renameTo or delete() not working

Tags: java, file, java-io

I am writing a program that "deletes" a line in a text file. How ever It is failing to both delete the original file and rename the new file.

What happens is, it will save the lines I want to save under the file name "temp.txt". However What it should do is delete the original file(TaskList.txt) and then rename temp.txt as TaskList.txt can anyone help? Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.*;

class DeleteTask implements ActionListener{

  private static Scanner x;
  JFrame frame;
  JButton deleteButton;
  JTextField delete;
  JLabel label;

public void completedTask()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setTitle("Delete Task");
    delete = new JTextField(10);
    deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
    deleteButton.addActionListener(this);
    label = new JLabel ("Enter task name");

    frame.add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(delete,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(deleteButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String filePath = "TaskList.txt";
    String removeTerm= delete.getText();
    removeRecord(filePath,removeTerm);
    frame.dispose();
}   

public static void removeRecord(String filePath, String removeTerm)
{
    String tempFile = "temp.txt";
    File oldFile = new File(filePath);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);
    String id = "" ;  String name = "" ; String age = ""; String descript = "";
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");


        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            id = x.next();
            name = x.next();
            age = x.next();
            descript = x.next();
            if(!id.equals(removeTerm))
            {
                pw.println(id + ", " + name + ", " + age + ", " + descript);
            }
        }
            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filePath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);

    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're ignoring any errors that occur (swallowing all exceptions). Remove the `catch` block (or rethrow if an exception is caught) and you'll see what's going wrong.

Comment: 1) Sort this out in a command line app. The stated problem really has little if anything to do with Swing. (Tag removed.) 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem repeated in this question. 3) `catch(Exception E)
    {

    }` should at the least be `catch(Exception E)
    {
E.printStackTrace(); 
    }` 4) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @DanielPryden I tried that, It says there is northing wrong.